# Infer generic type in function to Object.Type variable

Tags: swift, generics

In my project I created some functions that allows me to fetch any entities in CoreData using generic:

```
// Generic
func getAll<T: NSManagedObject>() -> [T] {  /* fetchrequest */ }

// Usage
let myObjectList: [MyObject] = getAll()
```

by specifying thetype of `myObjectList` to `[MyObject]` it infers the generic parameter in getAll and everything works fine until here.

Now I am using MVVM to my project and I am trying to reload a tableview based on the Type of the NSManagedObject currently specified in the ViewModel.

```
class MyViewModel {
    var coreDataObjectType: NSManagedObject.Type
    
    init(_ type: NSManagedObject.Type) {
        self.coreDataObjectType = type
    }
}
```

When I try to print the type it works fine but I did not manage to make my `getAll` function to work with that variable type :

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print("\(viewModel?.coreDataObjectType)") // successfully print `MyObject` type 

        getAll() // How to use coreDataObjectType to infer generic type? 

        return 0
    }
```

---

What I have tried so far :

creating a function that would deduce the type of MyObject

```
// instanciate a list of T? 
func deduce<T>(_ type: T.Type) -> [T] {
   return [T]()
}

... 

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    var myObjectList = deduce(viewModel?.coreDataObjectType!)
    myObjectList = getAll() //  tries to fetch the `NSManagedObject` type instead of `MyObject` type and fails

    return myObjectList.count
}
```

How can I infer `getAll` generic type with my `NSManagedObject.Type` variable? Thanks

Comment: You're mixing two things that are fundamentally incompatible. `coreDataObjectType` is has type `NSManagedObject.Type`, that is to say, its values are metatypes objects at runtime. `getAll()` is generic over a `T: NSManagedObject`. Generics are a compile time feature for making specializations of similar code. The compiler has no way to know what runtime value `coreDataObjectType` might have, so it has no way to pick the appropriate generic specialization of `getAll()`at compile time. Either both pieces of code need to use metatypes, or both need to be generic.

Comment: Understood, so you suggest me to make my whole ViewModel generic and recreate an instance each time I change of Object, rather than dynamically change ObjectType?

Comment: IDK your use case, or why it would make sense to change an object type for a particular instance, but in any case. Generics won't quite help you there, because even if `MyViewModel` was generic, how would you use it? YOu would need to know `MyViewModel<WhatGoesHere?>`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Alexander answer I got rid of the dynamic `var coreDataObjectType: NSManagedObject.Type`. As he stated :

> You're mixing two things that are fundamentally incompatible. coreDataObjectType is has type NSManagedObject.Type, that is to say, its values are metatypes objects at runtime. getAll() is generic over a T: NSManagedObject. Generics are a compile time feature

So With a different approach, I made my ViewModel generic itself and reload my view each time it is set to another value

**The ViewModel**

```
protocol MyViewModelProtocol: UITableViewDelegate & UITableViewDataSource {}

class MyViewModel<T: NSManagedObject>: MyViewModelProtocol {
    init(_ type: T.Type) {}

    // MARK: - TableView Delegate and Datasource
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        let all: [T] = coreDataStack.context.getAll()
        return all.count
    }
}
```

**The ViewController**

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    var viewModel: ListMasterViewModelProtocol? {
        didSet {
            bindViewModel()
        }
    }

    fileprivate func bindViewModel() {
        tableView.delegate = viewModel
        tableView.dataSource = viewModel
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

From now on, each time I set `myViewcontroller.viewModel = MyViewModel(MyObject1.self)` it reloads the tableview for the new Object type.

Comment: Your view controller shouldn't be responsible for table delegates and data sources. It's doing way to much, made worse by the fact that you're trying to shoe horn in the ability to display multiple types of objects in a single VC

Comment: The thing is, if I do not carry the type of my object along I wont be able to pass it to my detailViewController (this viewController is the RootViewController of a SplitViewController). I will not exactly display multiple objects in my tableview, I will cast the NSManagedObject to a protocol that allow me to display it in a TableViewCell. But I need to carry the Type along. If you have any suggestion to improve it I would take

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more? What exactly do you mean by "I need to carry the type along?". Back-forths like this are hard over comments, hopefully we'll generate enough spam for a chatroom to be made for us haha